# Is is possible to formulate an equation for the B-H curve when a magnetic field is applied through an iron ball bearing of diameter 5 mm?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am trying to find a mathematical model to show the relationship between B and H when a magnetic field is applied through an iron ball bearing. For simplicity, the ball bearing is 100% iron and also has a diameter of 5 mm. Is there a way to obtain an equation that expresses the B-H relationship?

Comment: Are you trying to measure the B vs. H curve, or just use it in calculations? If it is the latter, the B vs. H (magnetization) curve is a property of the material (iron) and doesn't depend on the geometry.

Comment: I am just using it in calculations, yes. Thanks for the heads up. Would you know what equation fits for iron in that case?

Comment: Magnetization in magnetic materials is complicated by the fact that they are hysteretic, so normally there is no single curve that describes their magnetization, but look here for a commonly used model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiles–Atherton_model. You can find model parameters online for specific materials, including iron.

Comment: Ah, thank you !